# php edit the last char in the last occurrence of a element within an array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, replace, matching

I'm a novice php programmer and having a problem assembling this code to work.
what I'm tiring to to is this,

```
From this:
----------------------------
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => apples,
            [1] => oranges,
            [2] => lettuce,
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => bananas,
            [1] => grapes,
            [2] => cabbage,
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => pears,
            [1] => mangoes,
            [2] => celery,
        )

)

----------------------------
To this:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => apples,
            [1] => oranges,
            [2] => lettuce?
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => bananas,
            [1] => grapes,
            [2] => cabbage?
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => pears,
            [1] => mangoes,
            [2] => celery?
        )

)
---------------------------
```

As you can see I'm tiring to replace the "," with a "?" question mark on each last char of each last element in each sub-array.

code-wise this is where I'm up to now:

```
    $array = array("apples,", "oranges,", "lettuce,", "bananas,", "grapes,", "cabbage,", "pears,", "mangoes,", "celery,");

    $subarrays = array_chunk($array, 3);
    print_r($miniarrays);

    foreach ($subarrays as $value){

    //$output1 = array_slice($value, 2, 1, true); #<== required maybe?
    $output1 = array_slice($value, 2, 1);
    print_r($output1); #<== debug purposes only

     foreach ($output1 as $val){

     $locate = $val[strlen($val)-1];
     print_r($result); #<== debug purposes only

     //foreach ($result as $val2) #<== required maybe?
     $output3 = strtr($locate, ",", "?");
     //echo $output2;
     print_r($output3); #<== debug purposes only
    }
   }
```

-

Trouble is I'm pointer locked and I've got string functions and array functions interacting with each other and at the same time tiring to traverse each sub-array. I tried functionalizing the code but can't figure out how to get php to display the original array structure with the question mark edits on each of the last chars on the last elements in each array, Yaakes.

As stated I am a novice and this is one of the hardest functions I've ever engaged in. I'm also tiring to find a better way of doing this without using the php string functions, only array functions as I think my approach is wrong. Any suggestions, pseudo code or knowledge and direction would be most grateful to improve my understanding on this subject, thanks~

Comment: From the looks of it you are mixing data with display formatting. Life's easier when you simply store the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are over complicating your solution, just loop through every three elements and combine them:

```
$arr = array("apples,", "oranges,", "lettuce,", "bananas,", "grapes,", "cabbage,", "pears,", "mangoes,", "celery,");
$result = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i+=3){
    $s = $arr[$i + 2];
    $s[strlen($s) - 1] = '?';
    $result[] = array($arr[$i], $arr[$i + 1], $s);
}
```

This will have issues with the last elements if the size of the array is not a multiple of 3.

Comment: That's not exactly what he was looking for - he presented a multidimensional array in his question.

Comment: @Sam Dufel: He converts his single dimensional array into a multi-dimensional array in his code (see the array_chunk part).  I just simplified it.

Comment: beautiful coding, very elegant too!, that's exactly what I was tiring to do. one of my weakness's is in this syntax style, as you can see I'm tiring to utilize object orientated programming which was giving me a headache.

Comment: @bobywww: PHP can be confusing with it's plethora of built in methods.

Answer (score 0):

As a function for multidimensional arrays:

```
<?php

    // Start array
    $array = array(array("apples", "oranges", "lettuce"),array("bananas", "grapes", "cabbage"),array("pears", "mangoes", "celery"));

    $newArray = addtoarray($array, "?");

    // Echo out the new array
    foreach ($newArray as $aKey => $aValue) {

        echo "Array: {$aKey}<br />";

        foreach ($aValue as $key => $value) {

            echo "Key: ". $key . " - Value: " . $value . "<br />";
        }

        echo "<br />";
    }

    function addtoarray($array, $stringtoadd) {

        $newArray = array();

        foreach ($array as $aValue) {

            $count = count($aValue);

            $tArray = array();

            foreach ($aValue as $key => $value) {

                if ($key == $count - 1) {

                    array_push($tArray, $value . $stringtoadd);
                }
                else {

                    array_push($tArray, $value);
                }
            }

            array_push($newArray, $tArray);
        }

        return $newArray;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach ($subarrays as $value){
    //replaces all occurences of ',' with '?' within the last element of the subarray
    $value[sizeof($value)-1] = str_replace(',', '?', $value[sizeof($value)-1]);
}
```

OR

```
foreach ($subarrays as $value){
    //replaces last character with '?' within the last element of the subarray
    $value[sizeof($value)-1] = substr($value[sizeof($value)-1], 1, strlen($value[sizeof($value)-1])-1) . '?';
}
```

OR a more legible version:

```
foreach ($subarrays as $value){
    //replaces last character with '?' within the last element of the subarray
    $str = $value[sizeof($value)-1];
    $value[sizeof($value)-1] = substr($str, 1, strlen($str)-1) . '?';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the preg_replace function as -

```
$array = array("apples,", "oranges,", "lettuce,", "bananas,", "grapes,", "cabbage,", "pears,", "mangoes,", "celery,");

for($i=2;$i<count($array);$i=$i+3)
  $array[$i]= preg_replace('/^([a-z]+),$/','${1}?',$array[$i]);

print_r($array);
```

Comment: Isn't that preg_replace more complicated than it needs to be? `preg_replace('/,$/', '?', $array[$i];`